# A Nice Wavy Message

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual

```
                                                                           Σ
                                                                       ᴎ___|___z
                                                                           |
                                                                           m
                                                                   (Informative Only)                                     
     - - - - - (-1) - - - -(-0.5) - - - - 0 - - - - - (0.5)- - - - (1) - - - - - - -  
                                          !                                
                                      *   |
                                   *      |
                                *         |
                             K*           |
                              *           |
                                 *        |
                                    *     |
                                        * |
                                          * 
                                           *
                                          |     *
                                          |         *
                                          |            *
                                          |             *M
                                          |             *
                                          |            *
                                          |         *  
                                          |      *
                                          |   *
                                          |* 
                                         *
                                      *   |
                                   *      |
                                *         |
                             N*           |
                              *           |
                                 *        |
                                    *     |
                                        *   
                                          *
                                          |     *
                                          |         *
                                          |            *
                                          |             *
                                          |             *S
                                          |            *
                                          |         *  
                                          |      *
                                          |   *
                                          |* 
                                         *
                                      *   |
                                   *      |
                                *         |
                             T*           |
                              *           |
                                 *        |
                                    *     |
                                        * |
                                          * 
                                           *
                                          |     *
                                          |         *
                                          |            *
                                          |             *P
                                          |             *
                                          |            *
                                          |         *  
                                          |      *
                                          |   *
                                          |* 
                                         *
                                      *   |
                                   *      |
                                *         |
                             X*           |
                              *           |
                                 *        |
                                    *     |
                                        * |
                                          *
                                          |  *
                                          |    * 
                                          |      *
                                          |       *  
                                          |        *X     
                                          |        *         
                                          |      *            
                                          |    *            
                                          | *
                                          *
                                      *   |
                                   *      |
                                *         |
                             N*           |
                              *           |
                                 *        |
                                    *     |
                                        * |
                                          * 
                                           *
                                          |     *
                                          |         *
                                          |            *
                                          |             *I
                                          |             *
                                          |            *
                                          |         *  
                                          |      *
                                          |   *
                                          |* 
                                         *
                                      *   |
                                   *      |
                                *         |
                             R*           |
                              *           |
                                 *        |
                                    *     |
                                        *   
                                          *
                                          |     *
                                          |         *
                                          |            *
                                          |             *
                                          |             *J
                                          |            *
                                          |         *  
                                          |      *
                                          |   *
                                          |* 
                                         *
                                      *   |
                                   *      |
                                *         |
                             S*           |
                              *           |
                                 *        |
                                    *     |
                                        * |
                                          * 
                                           *
                                          |     *
                                          |         *
                                          |            *
                                          |             *B
                                          |             *
                                          |            *
                                          |         *  
                                          |      *
                                          |   *
                                          |* 
                                         *
                                      *   |
                                   *      |
                                *         |
                             G*           |
                              *           |
                                 *        |
                                    *     |
                                        * |
                                          *
                                          |  *
                                          |    * 
                                          |      *
                                          |       *  
                                          |        *U     
                                          |        *         
                                          |      *            
                                          |    *            
                                          | *
```

**Help me *turn* this nice looking wave into a message!**

**Note** Assume each waveform = (+-) 0.5

Comment: At the end I see BG in there, followed by 'U'. Did you want to tell me something? :P

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil The message is for the one who finds it. So, it may be you. Who knows :-)

Comment: @humn Looks amusing isn't it? But tbh, it is not a part of message but serves a purpose in guiding how to look at the wave. :) And yes, I was motivated by your puzzle designs for making this one.

Comment: Thanks to the compass lettering and your ascii visuals, user @Techidiot, my screen is now happily sideways and in a monospace editor.

Comment: @humn I just used my mobile to view the puzzle. It seems the mobile browser doesn't show the letter "S" on the compass correctly. But anyway, one can assume it :)

Comment: I guess the Sigma sign in the compass could refer to Sigma **in math**. EDIT: Oh wait it's just a 90 degree turned W

Comment: @SIGSEGV FYI, I suck at math and would never dare to touch those complicated signs :-) As the picture says, its informative and just provides as way to look at the wave. Now, that I have added the numbers, the compass doesn't matter at all. Hope that helps.

Comment: Hmm. As it seems, The Hill height (As I will call) of each character is different from each other. Is that a part of how to solve it? P.S. pls don't make me count the absolute value of each y value and sort by that ;_;

Comment: @SIGSEGV Cleared your doubt :-)

Comment: @Techidiot Great, Now my hope of making a successful answer by that is broken :)

Comment: 'Help me *turn* this nice looking wave into a message!' Is there a meaning of setting 'turn' in italic? Is it a different meaning than it should normally be, like rotation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The message turns out to be:

> **That is how you roll.**

How can you read it?

> The curve can be rotated, so that the abscissa points right instead of downwards and the ordinate points upinstead of right¹.
>
>  In order of increasing abscissa values, the message reads:
>
>  **KMNSTPXXNIRJSBGU**
>
>  The letters sit on alternating minima and maxima of the sine curve, so let's take the next or previous letter in the alphabet depending on whether the the ordinate value is negative or positive:
>
>  **LLORUOYWOHSITAHT**
>
>  Now read the message bckwards³ and insert spaces as appropriate.
>
>  ________
>  ¹) The compass rose and the scale were supposed to hint at this, but it turns out that the rotation isn't really needed.
>
>  ²) It is not clear why the absolute value of the extrema should be 0.5 uniformly. First, the X and U are closer to the x-axis than other letters and the absolute value of the minima and maxima differs visually (15 vs. 13 spaces). And why 0.5? Maybe I'm missing something here.
>
>  ³) I don't think that there is any hint towards reading the message backwards; it's just observation.

Comment: @M Oehm -

1) I thought I made it a little difficult to interpret and hence added those values to make it simpler. :-) You just need to bring -0.5 to 0.5 hence add 1 to the letter similarly for 0.5 to -0.5 remove 1 from the letter. 

2) The values as said were just assumptions as I didn't drew exact curves.

3) Yes, no hint for going backwards just to add a little twist :-) 

PS - If you see the edit history, I didn't had the values nor the turn thing.

Nice work! :)

Comment: ...So It was just everything I thought of? *aww darnit*